# Como realizar un temporizador con vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

Al mostrar la vista el tiempo debe estar de esta for:

00:00
hrs mnt

básicamente lo que deseo hacer es ir incrementando de 1 minuto o decrementar el temporizador de 1 en 1 minuto utilizando vuejs.

Comment: no veo esto como tema de VueJS, el temporizador se arma con JS puro y solo lo muestras en tu vista con ayuda de VueJS

Comment: como lo armarías ?

Answer (score 0):

Tan sencillo como esto, es puro JS no vuejs, pero ya lo implementas dentro de un componente de js

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```